# Hibernate запрос к БД

Tags: hibernate, запрос

Добрый день. Уважаемые колеги, подскажите, как правильно составить запрос именно в hibernate.
 есть маппинг :

```
  <class name="Department" table="department">
    <id name="id" column="id"><generator class="increment"/></id>
    <property name="name" not-null="true" />
    <property name="description" />
    <many-to-one name="employeesHeadId" class="objects.Employee" fetch="select">
        <column name="head_id" unique="true" />
    </many-to-one>
    <set name="employee" table="employee" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
        <key><column name="department_id" not-null="true" /></key>
        <one-to-many class="objects.Employee" />
    </set>
</class>

<class name="Employee" table="employee">

    <id name="id" column="id" ><generator class="increment"  /></id>
    <property name="hireDate" type="date" column="hire_date"/>
    <property name="salary" type="int" column="salary"/>
    <property name="name" not-null="true" type="string" />
    <many-to-one name="departments" class="objects.Department" fetch="select">
        <column name="department_id" not-null="true"  unique="true"/>
    </many-to-one>
    <one-to-one name="departmentHeadId" class="objects.Department" property-ref="employeesHeadId"/>
</class>
```

надо отобрать всех начальников отделов, пришедших до марта
есть вот такая реализация:

```
    hql = " FROM Department d  join d.employeesHeadId e WHERE MONTH(e.hireDate)< 3";
    query = session.createQuery(hql);
    List<Object[]> objects = (List<Object[]>) query.list();
    for(Object[] objects2:objects)
    {
        Employee employee = (Employee) objects2[1];
        System.out.println(employee.getName() + " " +employee.getHireDate());
    }
```

но надо сделать через select, чтобы не тянуть все данные.
Подскажите оптимальное решение, все мои варианты не работают

Comment: А что не работает? Напишите подробнее. И что за данные, которые не надо тянуть?

Comment: работает, только надо без join-а и с select-ом

Comment: `Employee.departmentHeadId` должно быть `one-to-many`, тогда будет более правильно (`Department.employeesHeadId` имеет связь `many-to-one`). А поскольку ИД начальника хранится в таблице отделов, то без join не обойтись.

Comment: условие именно такое, и еще select нужен.

Comment: Попробуйте так: `String hql = "select e FROM Employee e WHERE e.departmentHeadId is not null";` такой запрос должен выбрать всех начальников.

Comment: ок, попробую,  + свое условие

Comment: спасибо, сработало, только не is not null, а is not empty